# Modifying output of Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell

I was running this command line command in powershell by using Invoke-Command and I was wondering if i could format the output?

```
$domainFirewall = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {netsh advfirewall show domain}
```

If have tried doing with no luck

```
$domainFirewall.(Property)
$domainFirewall | Select -Property (Property)
```

Comment: `netsh` does not output objects. You will have to parse it yourself. Unfortunately.

Comment: Rip me, I found findstr and i think i can pipe to it in powershell to get the output i want

Comment: You can definitely parse it inside Powershell, but you have to use some regex or string acrobatics to get what you want.  ;-)

Comment: Use powershell commands, if available in your version of windows `Get-NetFirewallProfile domain`

Comment: As an aside: to run `netsh advfirewall show domain` locally, there is no need for `Invoke-Command` - just invoke it directly.